# Do Hydra and Manticore mobs only appear on higher difficulties?

Tags: titan-quest

I've been playing Titan Quest (without the expansion) for a while now.  In its Editor.exe tool, I've noticed a few mobs that I haven't seen in-game before, like the Hydra and Manticore.

Is this a bug that I didn't know about or does those (bosses) only appear on higher difficulties? I haven't ever gotten to legendary difficulty yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hydra and the Manticore both appear in higher difficulties. The high-difficulty-only bosses I remember are:

- Manticore
- Hydra
- Talos
- Dragon Lych

And they are all extremely nasty. Most of them (except Talos) do not appear on the main path and you don't have to defeat them. If you do try to take one of them down, be very careful and prepare in advance.

Comment: Oh, thats fine. I play as a brigand (Hunter + Rogue for massive pierce damage), I am a resistance junkie and haven't died once ... yet :P

Comment: I just hope they aren't pierce-resisting <no animals were hurt during the making of this word>